# Node js doesn't receive all the messages that the client sends

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is a sample of the code that I use to receive data from a client. The program works in this way: I establish a connection between a wifi microcontroller and the server with Nodejs through a socket, when this is done the client sends its data to the server, but it happens that the server receives only four messages and then it stops; then I wait few more minutes and the messages that I've sent meanwhile are all received at the same time.
This the server's code that works with express, I check what is the message and then I use the socket to send it to the microcontroller.

```
    `var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8000});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('Arrows'));
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });

app.post('/left',function(req,res){
  var direction = req.body.direction;
  if (direction === 'left') {
    console.log("direction chosen is: "+direction);
      ws.send('left');
  }
  if(direction === 'stop') {
    console.log(direction);
  ws.send('stop');
  }
});

app.post('/back',function(req,res){
  var direction = req.body.direction;

  if (direction === 'back') {
    console.log("direction chosen is: "+direction);
    ws.send('back');
  }
  if(direction === 'stop') {
    console.log(direction);
    ws.send('stop');
  }
});
});
app.listen(3000);
  console.log("Started on PORT 3000");`
```

This is a part of the client's code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('READY');

$("#left").on('mousedown', function(){
  console.log('EVENT');
  $.post("/left",{direction:'left'},function(data){
  });
});

$("#back").on('mousedown', function(){
  console.log('EVENT');
  $.post("/back",{direction:'back'},function(data){
  });
});
```

How can I receive all the messages that the client sends without any delay?

Comment: Doesn't seem anything wrong with your code. Check whether there is anything else in the code, other than the snippet you have posted, that is blocking the event loop.

Comment: I've edited the question with the whole code. Since I'm a rookie I don't know what are the causes of this delays, I find it odd that the program shows me only four messages at the time and then it blocks. Is there a conflict between the socket and express?